# Casting Y or N to bool C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Just for neatness sake I was wondering, whether it's possible to cast Y or N to a bool?  Something like this;

```
bool theanswer = Convert.ToBoolean(input);
```

The long version;

```
bool theanswer = false;
switch (input)
{
   case "y": theanswer = true; break;
   case "n": theanswer = false; break
}
```

Comment: Would you want the algorithm to bomb if the string is not "y" or "n"?

Comment: I was considering trying to catch the exception yes.

Comment: There's no built in support for this. I presume this is due to y/n being _localized_ information (yes/no) which depends on the current culture.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No, there's nothing built in for this.

However, given that you want to default to false, you can just use:

```
bool theAnswer = (input == "y");
```

(The bracketing there is just for clarity.)

You may want to consider making it case-insensitive though, given the difference between the text of your question and the code you've got. One way of doing this:

```
bool theAnswer = "y".Equals(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Note that using the specified string comparison avoids creating a new string, and means you don't need to worry about cultural issues... unless you *want* to perform a culture-sensitive comparison, of course. Also note that I've put the literal as the "target" of the method call to avoid `NullReferenceException` being thrown when `input` is `null`.

Comment: Nice guard against input being null in second example. Gotta remember that.

Comment: (input ?? "").Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); makes the intent clear, we check value of variables equal to some constants not vice versa. Its the same c++ debate of if (NULL==ptr)

Comment: you lose null values here only get Boolean

Comment: @Prageethgodage: I don't understand your comment... the OP didn't specify any requirement about nullable values. They specifically asked for a `bool`, and judging by my second sentence, I suspect that at some point there was a comment indicating that they wanted to default to `false`. That may not be your specific situation, of course.

Answer (score 8):

```
bool theanswer = input.ToLower() == "y";
```

Comment: Using .ToLower is considered as bad practice when comparing strings. Better use the equals function. Your method might work, but equals is better. Also your code does not handle iput being null (causes a nullpointer on the ToLower when input is null).

Comment: Brilliant stuff, thank you.  I'd like todo more reading into how to form these type of expressions.

Comment: @Gertjan - Please provide a link for consideration on best practices rather than making a blanket statement. Depending on the needs of the application, I would think a NullReferenceException would be expected at the level a piece such as this would be executed.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: Well I don't have a source by hand, but common logic tells you that using .ToLowers can cause nasty bugs if not applied to all variables in the correct way. FXCop warns when using .ToLower and suggests using ToUpperInvariant. I don't know the inner working sof the equals function, but .ToLower() comparison will create temporary strings for comparing. So possibly using .ToLower (or ToUpper) causes extra memory usage. Also the handling of null is done inside the function making your own code less messy.

Comment: @Joel Etherton - A `NullReferenceException` is *always* a bug in your code, so it should definitely not be expected. If null is invalid it should be flagged with an `ArgumentNullException` or a contract failure which is far easier to track down. Ever tried to track down the source of a `NullReferenceException` without line numbers?

Comment: @Greg Beech - Yes, and the only thing that really has ever made it difficult is when it occurs across different threads. I don't necessarily disagree with you or @Gertjan, but I am always ready to read any documentation cheerfully offered up.

Answer (score 5):

Create an extension method for string that does something similar to what you specify in the second algorithm, thus cleaning up your code:

```
public static bool ToBool(this string input)
{
    // input will never be null, as you cannot call a method on a null object
    if (input.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
         return true;
    }
    else if (input.Equals("n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
         throw new Exception("The data is not in the correct format.");
    }
}
```

and call the code:

```
if (aString.ToBool())
{
     // do something
}
```

Comment: Nice use of the extension method, but maybe it is better to make a parse on the boolean class (like the Int.Parse).

Comment: You cannot make an extension of a class that you cannot have an instance of..in other words, you cannot have a extension to a static class.

Comment: Any reason for using StartsWith rather than Equals? I thing "not very much" is probably just as invalid as "true" :) (I'd also recommend using StringComparison, as per my answer. If you *are* going to use `input.ToLower()`, I'd at least only call it once.)

Comment: I know I'm 7 years too late but your comment (and code) is incorrect; `input` can indeed be null. Extension methods are only syntactic sugar, the actual call is equivalent to `if (ExtensionClass.ToBool(aString)){ // do something }`

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Jon, there's nothing inbuilt like this. The answer posted by John gives you a correct way of doing. Just for more clarification, you can visit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

how about this.

```
bool theanswer = input.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

or yet safer version.

```
bool theanswer = "Y".Equals(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: If input is null it will give you an error. Better use the equals on "y" since that cannot not be a null.

Answer (score 0):

Or this?

```
bool CastToBoolean(string input)
{
    return input.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but solved other way.

```
bool b=true; 
        decimal dec; 
        string CurLine = "";        
        CurLine = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] splitArray = CurLine.Split(new Char[] { '=' });
        splitArray[1] = splitArray[1].Trim();
        if (splitArray[1].Equals("Y") || splitArray[1].Equals("y")) b = true; else b = false;
        CurChADetails.DesignedProfileRawDataDsty1.Commen.IsPad = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/bool-parse) has a handy class for parsing various string bools.

```
/// <summary>
/// Parse strings into true or false bools using relaxed parsing rules
/// </summary>
public static class BoolParser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the boolean value for this string
    /// </summary>
    public static bool GetValue(string value)
    {
       return IsTrue(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine whether the string is not True
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsFalse(string value)
    {
       return !IsTrue(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine whether the string is equal to True
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsTrue(string value)
    {
       try
       {
            // 1
            // Avoid exceptions
            if (value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // 2
            // Remove whitespace from string
            value = value.Trim();

            // 3
            // Lowercase the string
            value = value.ToLower();

            // 4
            // Check for word true
            if (value == "true")
            {
                return true;
            }

            // 5
            // Check for letter true
            if (value == "t")
            {
                return true;
            }

            // 6
            // Check for one
            if (value == "1")
            {
                return true;
            }

            // 7
            // Check for word yes
            if (value == "yes")
            {
                return true;
            }

            // 8
            // Check for letter yes
            if (value == "y")
            {
                return true;
            }

            // 9
            // It is false
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is called by;

```
BoolParser.GetValue("true")
BoolParser.GetValue("1")
BoolParser.GetValue("0")
```

This could probably be further improved by adding a parameter overload to accept an object.

Comment: I believe the two static methods there are supposed to be extension methods like this:

public static bool GetValue(**this** string value) => IsTrue(value);
public static bool IsFalse(**this** string value) => !IsTrue(value);

Answer (score 0):

[Wonea gave an "IsTrue" source example from DotNetPerls.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38570848/2499090) Here are two shorter versions of it:

```
public static bool IsTrue(string value)
{
    // Avoid exceptions
    if (value == null)
        return false;

    // Remove whitespace from string and lowercase it.
    value = value.Trim().ToLower();

    return value == "true"
        || value == "t"
        || value == "1"
        || value == "yes"
        || value == "y";
}
```

OR:

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<string> LOWER_TRUE_VALUES = new string[] { "true", "t", "1", "yes", "y" };

public static bool IsTrue(string value)
{
    return value != null
        ? LOWER_TRUE_VALUES.Contains(value.Trim().ToLower())
        : false;
}
```

Heck, if you want to get real short (and ugly), you can collapse that down to two lines like this:

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<string> LOWER_TRUE_VALUES = new string[] { "true", "t", "1", "yes", "y" };
public static bool IsTrue(string value) => value != null ? LOWER_TRUE_VALUES.Contains(value.Trim().ToLower()) : false;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    void StringInput(string str)
    {
        string[] st1 = str.Split(' ');

        if (st1 != null)
        {
            string a = str.Substring(0, 1);
            string b=str.Substring(str.Length-1,1);

             if(
                a=="^" && b=="^" 
                || a=="{" && b=="}" 
                || a=="[" && b=="]"
                ||a=="<" && b==">" 
                ||a=="(" && b==")"
                )

            {
                Console.Write("ok Formate correct");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Sorry incorrect formate...");
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ubaid: ;
        Program one = new Program();
        Console.Write("For exit Press N ");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("Enter your value...=");
        string ub = Console.ReadLine();

        if (ub == "Y" || ub=="y" || ub=="N" || ub=="n" )
        {
            Console.Write("Are your want to Exit Y/N: ");
            string ui = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ui == "Y" || ui=="y")
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                goto ubaid;
            }

        }
        one.StringInput(ub);           
        Console.ReadLine();
        goto ubaid;
    }
}
```

Comment: My idea was to produce something small and concise, this code is way too much.