# Boolean result property c#

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm setting up a class that parses information input from a file and a part of that is deciding whether a person is a senior or veteran or not. Here is the source code for when I bring in from the file.

```
public static SalesInfo Parse(string stringValue)
{
  string[] words;
  SalesInfo person = new SalesInfo();

  words = ParseCsvString(stringValue.Trim());
  person.ID = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
  person.Name = words[1];
  person.City = words[2];
  person.Senior = words[3]; //this has red underline can't convert string to bool
  person.Veteran = words[4]; //this has red underline can't convert string to bool
  person.PurDate = Date.Parse(words[5]);
  person.ItemPrice = double.Parse(words[6]);
  person.Quantity = int.Parse(words[7]);

  return person;
}
```

and here is a line from the file as an example.

`2546,"Garfield, Janice",Neosho,Y,N,11/23/2016,289.68,4`

currently my property for senior and veteran are empty as follows

```
public bool Veteran
{
  get
  {
    return this.veteran;
  }
  set
  {

  }
}

public bool Senior
{
  get { return this.senior; }
  set { }
}
```

i know I need to send the values of 'Y' or 'N' to be checked by the bool properties of senior and veteran but I'm struggling to figure out where if possible to convert the char to a bool and return true or false to get the correct input from the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting Y or N to bool C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716845/casting-y-or-n-to-bool-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers provide such redundant solutions, you do not have to check the condition and then assign the same identical comparison to a property.

You can simply:

```
person.Senior = words[3] == "Y";
person.Veteran = words[4] == "Y";
```

This will assign the result of the comparison directly to the boolean property.

Comment: so any other value besides "y" will be represented as false correct?

Comment: Correct. It will check for "Y" and everything else is false.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a Boolean.

person.Senior = words[3].ToLower() == "y" ? true : false;

Comment: thank you. one question.. I'm assuming with the `? true : false;` part, the value is quotations is what represents true and any other value is false? just guessing, I'm not sure what ? means.

Comment: This is the conditional operator expression.

(condition) ? [true path] : [false path];

Answer (score -1):

Just add a check in there first:

```
  SalesInfo person = new SalesInfo();

  words = ParseCsvString(stringValue.Trim());
  person.ID = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
  person.Name = words[1];
  person.City = words[2];
  string senior = words[3]; 
  if (senior == "Y"){ person.Senior = true; }
  else { person.Senior = false; }
```

Then do the same for Veteran.

Comment: thank you i actually ended up doing this right after i asked this question lol